# Qtablewidget remove black space PyQt5

Tags: python, python-3.x, qt, pyqt5

I am trying to remove a redundant space in `QTableWidget`. I am using PyQt5.

This is the code

```
    self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.centralwidget)
    self.tableWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 500, 351))
    self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
    self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(3)

    self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(["name", "pass", "Id" ])
    self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
```

You can see the issue in image below.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use the [stretchLastSection](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#stretchLastSection-prop) property

```
 self.tableWidget.horizontalHeader().setStretchLastSection(True);
```

Comment: invalid syntax  ( -> )

Comment: Thank you It is work fine but I should use True not true

Comment: @Adel, try `True` instead